# Verb in dictionary form + まで versus te-form + まで

Tags: grammar, particle-まで

From [this site](https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7):

> お金を払うまでテストを受けたくない。
> I don't want to go to the extent of paying money to take the test. (given translation)

I'm confused by the English translation. I would have translated this as "I don't want to take the test **until** I've paid the money".

For the English translation they have given I would have written お金を払**って**までテストを受けたくない.

Can both a verb in dictionary form + まで and a verb in te-form + まで both mean "to the extent that"? Or, is this a translation error? If so, is there any nuance difference between them?

Comment: The linked site says 払ってまで in a similar sentence in the first tab. It must be the Japanese sentence in the second tab that is wrong, rather than the English translation.

Comment: サイトの例文が間違ってますよね。（「お金を払うまでテストを受けたくない」って思う人なんかいるかなあ、普通・・）

Comment: @aguijonazo Except that the grammar structure at the top of the first tab explicitly says "Verb［る］+ まで(も)" so the whole thing is hopelessly confused. That's why I had doubts. But thanks for the confirmation. Happy for this to be closed.

Comment: That site is not very good. 夜中まで in 夜中まで日本語の文法を勉強している in the second tab would be understood as “till midnight.”